# How to use Array Loop in iMacros?

Tags: imacros

```
VERSION BUILD=1005 RECORDER=CR
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES

URL GOTO=https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=923002021392&text=Great%20Offer%20For%20Karachites!%20Get%20a%20Free%20Squishy%20StressBall%20By%20Just%20Paying%20Rs%20200%20Delivery.%20Get%20your%20free%20Ball%20at:%20http://netlify.com/%20Have%20fun.

TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Send
WAIT SECONDS=10

TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=DATA-ICON:send&&CLASS:

URL GOTO=https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=923002021397&text=Great%20Offer%20For%20Karachites!%20Get%20a%20Free%20Squishy%20StressBall%20By%20Just%20Paying%20Rs%20200%20Delivery.%20Get%20your%20free%20Ball%20at:%20http://netlify.com/%20Have%20fun.
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Send

WAIT SECONDS=10

TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=DATA-ICON:send&&CLASS:

URL GOTO=https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=923002025509&text=Great%20Offer%20For%20Karachites!%20Get%20a%20Free%20Squishy%20StressBall%20By%20Just%20Paying%20Rs%20200%20Delivery.%20Get%20your%20free%20Ball%20at:%20http://netlify.com/%20Have%20fun.
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Send

WAIT SECONDS=10
```

I have a list of 1000 Numbers, and I can't add more than 50 lines, how can I use an Array or Loop?
As you see that link has different phone numbers, I want those number to be taken from Array or txt files.

Comment: I edited your Post @OP, and added some Formatting to your Script + corrected quite a few Typos and improved the Punctuation a bit... SOF Users don't like Scripts without the correct Formatting (=> 4x Spaces at the Beginning of each Line, very cumbersome, I completely agree...), I guess you may thank me a bit or your Qt would have gotten quite a few '-1' only for that..., ah-ah...!

Comment: Hum, and you may want to mention your FCI (Full Config Info), here and on the iMacros Forum if you ever want me to answer any of your Threads... (But I don't help for Spam anyway, just to let you know...)

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following code:

```
SET !VAR1 EVAL("[923002021392, 923002021397, 923002025509][{{!LOOP}} - 1];")
URL GOTO=https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone={{!VAR1}}&text=Great%20Offer%20For%20Karachites!%20Get%20a%20Free%20Squishy%20StressBall%20By%20Just%20Paying%20Rs%20200%20Delivery.%20Get%20your%20free%20Ball%20at:%20http://netlify.com/%20Have%20fun.
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Send
WAIT SECONDS=10
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=DATA-ICON:send&&CLASS:
```

Play this macro repeatedly (in loop mode).
Hope it helps.

Comment: Interesting Sol, #Shugar, not working "as is" directly, I mentioned your Sol and posted a few Comments in @OP's parallel Thread on the iMacros Forum:
https://forum.imacros.net/viewtopic.php?f=21&t=29857#p80443  (You'll get my "+1" once your Script works directly, ah-ah...! Even if hum..., I wouldn't have answered this Qt as the Intent is completely Spam from the OP, for which I never help...)

Comment: I've updated the code. Perhaps I missed something important before - Chrome is not in my everyday use. @chivracq, thanks for quoting.

Comment: Yep, very good, exactly the mini-Edit I had done also to your first "Attempt" to get it to work... (Good for a '+1' now, ah-ah...!)  Like I mentioned on "our Forum", I also use the same Functionality (on v8.8.2 + v8.9.7 for FF (which don't have the same Limitations like v10.x for CR/FF))...